# @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin installed but throw error in vs code lint task and ask for non existing @typescript-eslint package

Tags: npm, react-scripts, eslintrc, typescript-eslint

create project with `"react-scripts": "^4.0.3"` boilerplate and in order to include **eslintrc.js** file in the react with typescript project,I have tried `eslint --init` and it creates a default *eslintrc.js* and below is the content.

having eslint v 7.32.0 in global

*eslintrc.js*

```
module.exports = {
  env: {
    browser: true,
    es2021: true,
  },
  extends: [
    'eslint:recommended',
    'plugin:react/recommended',
    'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended',
  ],
  parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaFeatures: {
      jsx: true,
    },
    ecmaVersion: 12,
    sourceType: 'module',
  },
  plugins: ['react', '@typescript-eslint'],
  rules: {},
};
```

but es lint task in vs code was throwing error

> (node:37609) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Failed to load plugin
> '@typescript-eslint' declared in '.eslintrc.js': Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null

*package.json*

```json
"devDependencies": {
    "@types/classnames": "^2.3.1",
    "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.19",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.3.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.33.0",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.25.2",
    "typescript": "^4.4.4"
  },
 "dependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.15",
    "@types/node": "^12.0.0",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.5",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "^4.0.3",
    "redux": "^4.1.1",
}
```

now when I run below command to install the missing package

> npm i --save-dev @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin

it throws error in terminal

```sh
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: react-app@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: @typescript-eslint/parser@4.33.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@typescript-eslint/parser
npm ERR!   dev @typescript-eslint/parser@"^4.33.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @typescript-eslint/parser@"^5.0.0" from @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@5.0.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin
npm ERR!   dev @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@"*" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in
```

So as per suggestion tried with option

> npm i --save-dev @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin --legacy-peer-deps

it was installed successfully but with higher version (5.x) than the `@typescript-eslint/parser` version and as per mentioned on the [eslint-plugin documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin)

*It is important that you use the same version number for @typescript-eslint/parser and @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin.*

so re install package of similar version

```sh
> npm install --save-dev @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@4.33.0
```

but in vs code it still throw error of

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Failed to load plugin '@typescript-eslint' declared in '.eslintrc.js': Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null

so I have tried to install

> npm install --save-dev @typescript-eslint

but it throw error

```sh
npm ERR! code EINVALIDTAGNAME
npm ERR! Invalid tag name "@typescript-eslint": Tags may not have any characters that encodeURIComponent encodes.
```

also tried by updating es lint latest version 8.0 but it creates another problem.

I know that this is because I am trying to install a package which does not exist but how to solve this?  am I missing something here.

- vscode - v 1.61.1
- ubuntu - v 20.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after checking at [eslint plugin naming convention](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring/plugins), found out that I have to install the missing *@typescript-eslint* as following syntax

> npm install --save-dev @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin

this solved the issue but new error coming that react version is not specified , so added that in "settings" key.

eslintrc.js

```js
// eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
module.exports = {
  env: {
    browser: true,
    es2021: true,
  },
  extends: [
    'eslint:recommended',
    'plugin:react/recommended',
    'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended',
  ],
  parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaFeatures: {
      jsx: true,
    },
    ecmaVersion: 12,
    sourceType: 'module',
  },
  plugins: ['react', '@typescript-eslint'],
  rules: {
    '@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any': 'off',
    'react/react-in-jsx-scope': 'off',
    '@typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types': 'off',
  },
  settings: {
    react: {
      version: 'latest',
    },
  },
};
```

*package.json*

```json
"devDependencies": {
    "@types/classnames": "^2.3.1",
    "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.19",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.3.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.33.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.33.0",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.25.2",
    "redux-devtools": "^3.7.0",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.9",
    "typescript": "^4.4.4"
  }
```

*tsconnfig.json*

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}
```